# Increase MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-headers, registry

I have a get request with a very large url which works.
But every subsquent calls fails because when this large url becomes 
a referer and then the whole header becomes larger than 16k and the request fails.

> The size of the request headers is too long.

I know I can fix this by using the [registry hack](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/820129). But I need to change this in the web.config.

Is that possible att all?

Please don't advice me to shorten the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No you can't change it from the web.config.**

You  can do it only by registry because this settings is used at kernel level (http.sys).

It will apply to all web sites and it has many implication and concern

so you have to decide if YOU REALLY NEED THIS?

you says to not advice to shorten the url but I think you're not really aware of the implication.

**The problems is your too long urls and not this setting**

you're just trying to work around the problem by changing a setting but definitely the problem will recur in other forms and other places

Comment: When on an intranet and you have a reporting tool and people need to be able to send these urls to each other the implication is only higer memory load for the server... And in that setting that is not an issue. But thx for the kernel part of it. That answers the question :)

Comment: @Archlight did you think about implementing an url-shortener?

Comment: Yes but the requests are not allowed out of the house so I would have to impliment my own so I decided not to.